# toUpperCase in Java does not work

Tags: java, string

I have a string:

```
String c = "IceCream";
```

If I use `toUpperCase()` function then it returns the same string, but I want to get `"ICECREAM"`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The code

```
String c = "IceCream";
String upper = c.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(upper);
```

correctly prints "ICECREAM". However, the original string c isn't changed. Strings in Java are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java) so all operations on the string return a new copy.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java

Comment: You could also just reassign the variable 
    **String c = "IceCream"; c = c.toUpperCase();** This should be included in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

Are you expecting the original variable, `c`, to have been changed by `toUpperCase()`? Strings are  immutable; methods such as `.toUpperCase()` return new strings, leaving the original un-modified:

```
String c = "IceCream";
String d = c.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(c); // prints IceCream
System.out.println(d); // prints ICECREAM
```

Answer (score 10):

The object can't be changed, because `String` is immutable. However, you can have the reference point to a new instance, which is all uppercase:

```
String c = "IceCream";
c = c.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to use it like this:

```
String c = "IceCream";
String upper_c = c.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: an alternative would also be `String c = "IceCream".toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with your locale. Try:

```
String c = "IceCream";
return c.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```