# Why is String immutable in Java?

Tags: java, string

I was asked in an interview why String is immutable

I answered like this:

> When we create a string in Java like `String s1="hello";` then an
> object will be created in **string pool(hello)** and **s1** will be
> pointing to **hello**. Now if again we do `String s2="hello";` then
> another object will not be created, but **s2** will point to `hello`
> because **JVM** will first check if the same object is present in
> **string pool** or not. If not present, then only a new one is created, else not.

Now if suppose Java allows string mutable then if we change **s1** to `hello world` then **s2** value will also be `hello world` so the Java String is immutable.

Is my answer right or wrong?

Comment: _Why_ is always difficult to answer. The most correct answer is probably: Because the language designers figured it was a good idea.

Comment: some reading: http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Comment: see also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069014/180100)

Comment: Your answer is not on the point. C++ `std::string` is mutable, but they have string pool as well (well, more correctly, character array pool).

Comment: Usually we design classes as immutable for them being thread safe and to optimize performance and memory consumption: if class is immutable all threads can only read the class and so every instance is thread safe. Immutable class instances have no need to re-allocate memory and so they are more CPU and memory effective.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The answer I told is incorrect?

Comment: @Pawanmishra possible duplicate of question title. I do not want *why String is immutable* I am asking *Is my answer is right or not*

Comment: @rocking To be honest, whether it's right or not kind of depends on how they read it. The thing is, Java can have a string pool *because* strings are immutable. If they decided to make strings mutable then they would not have used a string pool; so it may not be accurate to say "string pool, therefore immutable strings"; it's more the other way around. The *reasons* for choosing immutable strings are outlined below, and the string pool is a working strategy *because* of that. Still, your answer is not *incorrect*, it just doesn't seem complete. You'll just have to wait and see what they say.

Comment: (In other words; if you consider Security and Efficiency to be the primary design goals, then immutable strings are a means to meet those goals, and a string pool is an efficient implementation of immutable strings.)

Comment: @JasonC Thanks for helping.Do you think should I wait for jDeveloper answer or you have any better answer or should I wait for other answers?

Comment: @rocking I don't have an answer that's any better than the the links in the answers below (or in the question Pawan mishra linked). It's up to you if you want to wait for more answers or not.

Comment: Your answer is correct but some more factors are there for why string in java is immutable. [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-string-is-immutable/22398222#22398222)

Comment: @rocking: Your answer is correct one (you've mentioned string pool which is the means to make String being CPU and memory effective and the string pool is that useful because String is immutable). Probably, you should have added some words on thread safety.

Comment: @rocking your answer is just define how java string pool works. but the question is WHY?... why java do this....?

Comment: I simply cannot understand why this question was closed. The supposed related answer is not even about Java and does not address the main subject of this question, which is "why". For me this us one of those cases of an irresponsible community acting on question they know nothing about. I have nominated it to reopen.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo My question was whether the answer I gave is right or wrong but none has answered and instead they provided their answers

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Comment: MYSTERY CONTINUES :-D

Comment: @rocking That is a distinction without a difference. If your answer is correct it agrees with the others, and if it isn't orrect it wouldn't be much use merely to tell you 'no' without stating the real reason why it is so.

Answer (score 192):

`String` is immutable for several reasons, here is a summary:

- **Security**: parameters are typically represented as `String` in network connections, database connection urls, usernames/passwords etc. If it were mutable, these parameters could be easily changed.
- **Synchronization** and concurrency:  making String immutable automatically makes them thread safe thereby solving the synchronization issues.
- **Caching**: when compiler optimizes your String objects, it sees that if two objects have same value (a="test", and b="test") and thus you need only one string object (for both a and b, these two will point to the same object).
- **Class loading**: `String` is used as arguments for class loading. If mutable, it could result in wrong class being loaded (because mutable objects change their state).

That being said, immutability of `String` only means you cannot change it using its public API. You can in fact bypass the normal API using reflection. See the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable)**.

In your example, if `String` was mutable, then consider the following example:

```
  String a="stack";
  System.out.println(a);//prints stack
  a.setValue("overflow");
  System.out.println(a);//if mutable it would print overflow
```

Comment: How to could it affect the security?

Comment: Can someone explain Class loading with an example if possible ?

Comment: Concerning security, if I'm interested in changing connection parameters, it's straightforward at run-time (with a debugger, etc.). Concerning class loading, if `String` is mutable, then the class loader would take the string passed in, make a copy, and not change its copy. When thinking of a problem with mutable `java.lang.String`s, think of how C++ solves this problem (since it has mutable `std::string`s.

Comment: Regarding security, how can a mutable string be changed when the program is running ?

Comment: Since String is immutable, its hashcode is cached at the time of creation and it doesn’t need to be calculated again.

Comment: Ironically, [best practice in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) is to use a `char[]` instead of a `String` for passwords, so you can zero out the array afterwards. This avoids the possibility of some other code retaining a reference to the password, and removes the password from memory immediately rather than waiting for the garbage collector. So the immutability of `String` is a security problem!

Answer (score 47):

Java Developers decide Strings are immutable due to the following aspect **design, efficiency, and security**.

**Design**
Strings are created in a special memory area in java heap known as "String Intern pool". While you creating new String (Not in the case of using String() constructor or any other String functions which internally use the String() constructor for creating a new String object; String() constructor always create new string constant in the pool unless we call the method [intern()](http://java.dzone.com/articles/string-interning-what-why-and)) variable it searches the pool to check whether is it already exist.
If it is exist, then return reference of the existing String object.
If the String is not immutable, changing the String with one reference will lead to the wrong value for the other references.

According to [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-string-immutable-java) article on DZone:

> **Security**
>   String is widely used as parameter for many java classes, e.g. network connection, opening files, etc. Were String not immutable, a connection or file would be changed and lead to serious security threat.
>   Mutable strings could cause security problem in Reflection too, as the parameters are strings.
>
> **Efficiency**
>   The hashcode of string is frequently used in Java. For example, in a HashMap. Being immutable guarantees that hashcode will always the same, so that it can be cached without worrying the changes.That means, there is no need to calculate hashcode every time it is used.

Comment: Your understanding of the string pool is incorrect. String *constants* are created in the intern pool, but it's perfectly possible to have more than one string object with the same text in. I agree that strings being immutable enables pooling, but there's not as much pooling sa you've stated.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. String s1 = new String("test");  statement create new string constant in the intern pool unless we call the method intern(). Thank you  for deepen my knowledge about string intern pool.

Comment: It's more than just using the string constructor - almost *anything* which creates a new string, e.g. substring, split, concat etc will create new strings. Compile-time constants are the special case here, not the norm...

Comment: @JonSkeet substring(), concat(), replace() etc are internally use String constructor for creating new string object. 
Thank you for improving my answer.

Comment: @Alex Mathew In terms of efficiency we can use a wrapper object also as key for hashmap since they are also immutable in java.

Comment: @JonSkeet - All these answers say that immutability improves "security", but don't explain how. They all link to a vague dzone article which does not help either. The answers/link don't explain how a mutable string could be changed when the code is running. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 Let me tell my understanding. If you are sure your String obj is not passed/used anywhere else and used only in your DB connections, there is no need of immutability. Contrived Ex : Say you have your DB conn method which receives URL as String. Say some other class/method parses the URL from a file and passes to you. Say this calling method passes this String to some other method(say for logging) also. Now the same String obj is ref-ed by some other var in Logging class. If Logging class changes the val before you access, you ll see the changed val.

Answer (score 43):

We can not be sure of what was Java designers actually thinking while designing `String` but we can only conclude these reasons based on the advantages we get out of string immutability, Some of which are

#### 1. Existence of String Constant Pool

As discussed in [Why String is Stored in String Constant Pool](https://programmingmitra.com/2018/02/why-string-is-stored-in-constant-pool.html) article, every application creates too many string objects and in order to save JVM from first creating lots of string objects and then garbage collecting them. JVM stores all string objects in a separate memory area called String constant pool and reuses objects from that cached pool.

Whenever we create a string literal JVM first sees if that literal is already present in constant pool or not and if it is there, new reference will start pointing to the same object in SCP.

```
String a = "Naresh";
String b = "Naresh";
String c = "Naresh";
```

In above example string object with value `Naresh` will get created in SCP only once and all reference `a`, `b`, `c` will point to the same object but what if we try to make change in `a` e.g. `a.replace("a", "")`.

Ideally, `a` should have value `Nresh` but `b`, `c` should remain unchanged because as an end user we are making the change in `a` only. And we know `a`, `b`, `c` all are pointing the same object so if we make a change in `a`, others should also reflect the change.

But string immutability saves us from this scenario and due to the immutability of string object string object `Naresh` will never change. So when we make any change in `a` instead of change in string object `Naresh` JVM creates a new object assign it to `a` and then make change in that object.

So String pool is only possible because of String's immutability and if String would not have been immutable, then caching string objects and reusing them would not have a possibility because any variable woulds have changed the value and corrupted others.

And That's why it is handled by JVM very specially and have been given a special memory area.

#### 2. Thread Safety

An object is called thread-safe when multiple threads are operating on it but none of them is able to corrupt its state and object hold the same state for every thread at any point in time.

As we an immutable object cannot be modified by anyone after its creation which makes every immutable object is thread safe by default. We do not need to apply any thread safety measures to it such as creating synchronized methods.

So due to its immutable nature string object can be shared by multiple threads and even if it is getting manipulated by many threads it will not change its value.

#### 3. Security

In every application, we need to pass several secrets e.g. user's user-name\passwords, connection URLs and in general, all of this information is passed as the string object.

Now suppose if String would not have been immutable in nature then it would cause a serious security threat to the application because these values are allowed to get changed and if it is allowed then these might get changed due to wrongly written code or any other person who have access to our variable references.

#### 4. Class Loading

As discussed in [Creating objects through Reflection in Java with Example](https://programmingmitra.com/2016/05/creating-objects-through-reflection-in-java-with-example.html), we can use `Class.forName("class_name")` method to load a class in memory which again calls other methods to do so. And even JVM uses these methods to load classes.

But if you see clearly all of these methods accepts the class name as a string object so Strings are used in java class loading and immutability provides security that correct class is getting loaded by `ClassLoader`.

Suppose if String would not have been immutable and we are trying to load `java.lang.Object` which get changed to `org.theft.OurObject` in between and now all of our objects have a behavior which someone can use to unwanted things.

#### 5. HashCode Caching

If we are going to perform any hashing related operations on any object we must override the `hashCode()` method and try to generate an accurate hashcode by using the state of the object. If an object's state is getting changed which means its hashcode should also change.

Because String is immutable so the value one string object is holding will never get changed which means its hashcode will also not change which gives String class an opportunity to cache its hashcode during object creation.

Yes, String object caches its hashcode at the time of object creation which makes it the great candidate for hashing related operations because hashcode doesn't need to be calculated again which save us some time. This is why String is mostly used as `HashMap` keys.

Read More on [Why String is Immutable and Final in Java](https://programmingmitra.com/2018/02/why-string-is-immutable-and-final-in-java.html).

Comment: Regarding Security - How can the mutable string value get changed in memory ? How can another person get access to our variable references ?

Comment: It is not about how one can get access to the references it is what if somebody has access to those?  as mentioned "if String would not have been immutable in nature then it would cause a serious security threat to the application because these values are allowed to get changed and if it is allowed then these might get changed due to wrongly written code or any other person who have access to our variable references."

Comment: The how matters here. Its either possible to get access to the references or not. If possible, then can you name 1-2 techniques*** (i.e. the how) that can be used to do it ? If not possible, then the point about security is not applicable. *** Example - Name one technique to attack the DB of a web app --> SQL Injection. Do you know any techniques like this for attacking the references ?

Comment: As mentioned, "It can happen due to wrongly written code or any changes done by another person who has access to our variable references". e.g. Suppose String is mutable and you are writing some method which is using a string a string secret and again that string is getting passed to several another method in between and one of those methods is not written by you and that method made some changes into that string now after calling all these methods control returned your method and you are using that string again but it has been changed.

Comment: Please disclose any [affiliations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and do not use the site as a way to promote your site through posting. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NareshJoshi Your problem description implies improper code change. An improper code change doesn't make a language "not secure enough". A developer is free to represent password field as char[], which makes it mutable. There are no known Java specific Security issues if a developer was to use char[]. So how can having a Mutable String representation cause Security issues?

Comment: @DevAmitabh I never mentioned "the language is not secure enough", I just mentioned several secrets are stored using string and they are passed in between different methods and if String objects are not immutable then some improper code in one those methods can accidentally modify those secrets and cause problems to their caller method.

Answer (score 21):

Most important reason according to [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-string-immutable-java) article on DZone:

> **String Constant Pool**
>   ...
>   If string is mutable, changing the string with one reference will lead to the wrong value for the other references.
>
> **Security**
>
> String is widely used as parameter for many java classes, e.g. network connection, opening files, etc. Were String not immutable, a connection or file would be changed and lead to serious security threat.
>   ...

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @JasonC I just want to know if my answer is wrong or not.I had already attended the interview and waiting for result.If the answer told them is right then I will be selected

Comment: As per my knowledge your answer is correct, but immutable mean the reference will never be change the pointing location.All the best for your interview.

Comment: If accept your point #1, then all objects should be immutable.

Comment: Hi JDeveloper, I edited your answer to give proper attribution to the source of your answer. Remember to always use block quotes for verbatim copies of content. Thanks!

Comment: The DZone article contains *major* errors about the operation of the Strign pool. It is *only* for constants. *Ergo* the stated rationale is invalid.

Answer (score 12):

IMHO, this is the most important reason:

> String is Immutable in Java because String objects are **cached in
> String pool**. Since cached String literals are **shared between multiple
> clients** there is always a risk, where one client's action would affect
> all another client.

Ref: [Why String is Immutable or Final in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html)

Answer (score 5):

You are right. `String` in java uses concept of `String Pool` literal. When a string is created and if the string already exists in the pool, the reference of the existing string will be returned, instead of creating a new object and returning its reference.If a string is not immutable, changing the string with one reference will lead to the wrong value for the other references.

I would add one more thing, since `String` is immutable, it is safe for multi threading and a single String instance can be shared across different threads. This avoid the usage of synchronization for thread safety, Strings are implicitly `thread safe`.

Answer (score 2):

String is given as immutable by Sun micro systems,because string can used to store as key in map collection.
StringBuffer is mutable .That is the reason,It cannot be used as key in map object

Answer (score 1):

The most important reason of a String being made immutable in Java is **Security** consideration. Next would be **Caching**.

I believe other reasons given here, such as efficiency, concurrency, design and **string pool** follows from the fact that String in made immutable. For eg. String Pool could be created because String was immutable and not the other way around.

Check Gosling interview transcript [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/gosling3P.html)

> From a strategic point of view, they tend to more often be trouble free. And there are usually things you can do with immutables that you can't do with mutable things, such as cache the result. If you pass a string to a file open method, or if you pass a string to a constructor for a label in a user interface, in some APIs (like in lots of the Windows APIs) you pass in an array of characters. The receiver of that object really has to copy it, because they don't know anything about the storage lifetime of it. And they don't know what's happening to the object, whether it is being changed under their feet.
>
> You end up getting almost forced to replicate the object because you don't know whether or not you get to own it. And one of the nice things about immutable objects is that the answer is, "Yeah, of course you do." Because the question of ownership, who has the right to change it, doesn't exist.
>
> One of the things that forced Strings to be immutable was security. You have a file open method. You pass a String to it. And then it's doing all kind of authentication checks before it gets around to doing the OS call. If you manage to do something that effectively mutated the String, after the security check and before the OS call, then boom, you're in. But Strings are immutable, so that kind of attack doesn't work. That precise example is what really demanded that
>   Strings be immutable

Answer (score 0):

String class is `FINAL` it mean you can't create any class to inherit it and change the basic structure and make the Sting mutable.

Another thing instance variable and methods of String class that are provided are such that you can't change `String` object once created.

The reason what you have added doesn't make the String immutable at all.This all says how the String is stored in heap.Also string pool make the huge difference in performance

Comment: If class declared as final, it means that class can't be inherited, but it doesn't mean that class's instances fields can't be changed and so the class is immutable.

Comment: @Zeeshan: The example classes you give are all immutable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the great answers, I wanted to add a few points. Like Strings, Array holds a reference to the starting of the array so if you create two arrays `arr1` and `arr2` and did something like `arr2 = arr1` this will make the reference of `arr2` same as `arr1` hence changing value in one of them will result in change of the other one for example

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int[] b = a;
        a[0] = 8;
        b[1] = 7;
        System.out.println("A: " + a[0] + ", B: " + b[0]);
        System.out.println("A: " + a[1] + ", B: " + b[1]);
        //outputs
        //A: 8, B: 8
        //A: 7, B: 7
    }
}
```

Not only that it would cause bugs in the code it also can(and will) be exploited by malicious user. Suppose if you have a system that changes the admin password. The user have to first enter the `newPassword` and then the `oldPassword` if the `oldPassword` is same as the `adminPass` the program change the password by `adminPass = newPassword`. let's say that the new password has the same reference as the admin password so a bad programmer may create a `temp` variable to hold the admin password before the users inputs data if the `oldPassword` is equal to `temp` it changes the password otherwise `adminPass = temp`. Someone knowing that could easily enter the new password and never enter the old password and abracadabra he has admin access. Another thing I didn't understand when learning about Strings why doesn't JVM create a new string for every object and have a unique place in memory for it and you can just do that using `new String("str");` The reason you wouldn't want to always use `new` is because it's not memory efficient and it is slower in most cases [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14757978/7109836).

Answer (score 0):

If `HELLO` is your String then you can't change `HELLO` to `HILLO`. This property is called immutability property.

You can have multiple pointer String variable to point HELLO String.

But if HELLO is char Array then you can change HELLO to HILLO. Eg,

```
char[] charArr = 'HELLO';
char[1] = 'I'; //you can do this
```

**Answer:**

Programming languages have immutable data variables so that it can be used as keys in key, value pair. **String variables are used as keys/indices, so they are immutable**.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has little to do with security because, very differently, security practices recommend using character arrays for passwords, not strings. This is because an array can be immediately erased when no longer needed. Differently, a string cannot be erased, because it is immutable. It may take long time before it is garbage collected, and even more before the content gets overwritten.

I think that immutability was chosen to allow sharing the strings and they fragments easily. String assignment, picking a substring becomes a constant time operation, and string comparison largely also, because of the reusable hash codes that are part of the string data structure and can be compared first.

From the other side, if the original string is huge (say large XML document), picking few symbols from there may prevent the whole document from being garbage collected. Because of that later Java versions seemed moved away from this immutability. Modern C++ has both mutable (std::string) and from C++17 also immutable ([std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)) versions.

Answer (score -2):

From the `Security` point of view we can use this practical example:

```
DBCursor makeConnection(String IP,String PORT,String USER,String PASS,String TABLE) {

    // if strings were mutable IP,PORT,USER,PASS can be changed by validate function
    Boolean validated = validate(IP,PORT,USER,PASS);

    // here we are not sure if IP, PORT, USER, PASS changed or not ??
    if (validated) {
         DBConnection conn = doConnection(IP,PORT,USER,PASS);
    }

    // rest of the code goes here ....
}
```