# Why does java have StringBuilder or StringBuffer?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

There are many differences between `String` and (`StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`) like mutability and many string operations

May be this question seems a bit silly, but I want to know for the sake of programming paradigm.

I want to ask, why has Java implemented another class, `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` for a data structure like `String`. Why have they not given those features in `String` itself.

Why not make `String` itself thread-safe or provide some extra features that `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` has?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer

Comment: @bobs_007 - I know the difference between StringBuffer and StringBuilder, Please read my question i.e. bold in my post

Comment: If I could remember well String is Thread Safe!

Comment: `String` is immutable, `StringBuilder` is mutable. It's as simple as that. You can't add the `StringBuilder` features to `String`, because they're all about mutability.

Comment: @Lrrr  It's mutable, that is the purpose of introducing StringBuilder and StringBuffer. String is immutable but if you want to perform String based operations you have two choices, if you want it thread safe way without creating new instances of string you use StringBuffer

Comment: @Lrrr: Whoops, typo - fixed, thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet Its honor to even fix Jon Skeet's typos :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. String is immutable and there are many reason and also benefit to it. Why? and what the necessity of it? (very popular topic ) search or read those
   [why-is-string-immutable-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java)  or [why-string-is-immutable-in-java](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/)
2. Now Some one need to do frequent String operation here comes **StringBuffer**  which is thread safe (synchronized).
3. Some one don't need thread safety  here comes **StringBuilder**.

Now some one can still use  **StringBuffer** when thread safety is not necessary, but that would be slow. That's why both of them is important.

String's are differently handled by `jvm` If those features of `StringBuffer` was added it will not be immutable any more.

---

Update : point 2 and 3 are altered from the comment of @Jon Skeet.

Comment: What types of reasons are you trying to say about in your first point ?

Comment: Actually `StringBuffer` came before `StringBuilder`, and then Sun realized that it's incredibly rare to need its thread-safety, so they introduced `StringBuilder`. If `StringBuilder` had come first, I doubt that `StringBuffer` would ever have been introduced.

Comment: thanks Mr. @JonSkeet for making that clear.

Comment: reading those link will give you some idea and as I said its very popular topic so you can easily search .