# What other reasons are that a string in Java is immutable ?

Tags: string, immutability

I know that Java system treats a string as an immutable type because a string is always initialized with its fixed length. Another reason is Java want to make any strings in many safe threads, which is unmodified by any users. However, because I really want to learn a complete checklist of why Java's string is immutable, so I wonder if there are any other reasons along those above?

Comment: Here, [let me google that for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+are+java+strings+immutable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is String immutable in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

One other reason is efficiency: If strings were mutable, every call to `Class.getName`, `System.getProperty` or basically any method that returns a string would always have to make a fresh copy. If they didn’t, you could do the following:

```
"".getClass().setCharAt(11, 'p')
```

And from that point on, the `java.lang.String` class would be called `java.lang.Spring`.

Comment: decent example :)