# String object created or not by java code

Tags: java

For the following code :

String object will be created in heap area (not inside String pooled area):

```
String str = new String("very");
```

Now if I modify str to refer "good" like:

```
str = "good";
```

Will it modify the object "very" created in heap and change its value to "good" or will it create a new object of "good" in pool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is String immutable in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = new String("very");
```

`str` is a reference. Meaning it "points" to a string object.

When you do

```
str = "good"
```

you just make `str` point to a different object. You are not trying to change the contents of the object to which `str` points to.

If you did something like `str.Method()` this would be an attempt to do something on the object to which `str` points, but as string is immutable still you would get a new string object out of that.

But by simply doing

```
str = ...
```

You make reference point elsewhere, this would be common with all reference types.

Answer (score -1):

It will return a string object .
The String class is immutable, so that once it is created a String object cannot be changed. The String class has a number of methods, some of which will be discussed below, that appear to modify strings. Since strings are immutable, what these methods really do is create and return a new string that contains the result of the operation. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: what makes u to say its a contradiction ? just read answer properly

Answer (score -2):

```
String str=new String("very");
```

here str in the reference for the string object with value `"very"`.
and `new String("very")` is the referenced object created in java.
while "very" is the value which will be replaced by "Good" without creating any new object but in the same memory unit.