# How to override class variable value

Tags: java

This is sample reference example, for what I am looking Solution

Reference Example:

- Here demoName is global variable
- Somehow I need to define that variable on Class level which is : `String demo = demoName;`
- Now it needs to override variable value with local variable, when it call from local method.

  `void test(String name) {
              demoName = name;
              System.out.println("Local Value:" + demoName);
              System.out.println("Global Value:" + demo);
   }`

Here demoName becoming override with parameter value, But when +demo is taking class level value which is XYZ, I want it to be abc.

```
class demo1 {
    public static String demoName = "xyz";
}

public class demos extends demo1 {

    String demo = demoName;

    void test(String name) {
        demoName = name;
        System.out.println("Local Value:" + demoName);
        System.out.println("Global Value:" + demo);
    }

    @Test
    public void testtest() {
        test("abc");
    }    
}
```

[image]

**I want both value to be "abc" .**

Comment: That is, because `By demo = By.xpath(demoName);` is initialized when the class is created. And at this moment `demoName` is equal to `"xyz"`

Comment: Yes, Somehow I need to declare it on Class level. But, I am looking for is there is any possibility where it can override by local assignment. Something from this or Super.

Comment: Why not just declare `demo` inside the `test` method?

Comment: When you're going to use outdated programming patterns (like global variables and static access) why don't you choose a Language that supports that more like C/C++?

Comment: A variable is only evaluated once on construction. If you want it to be re-evaluated you need a method.

Comment: @Lino For some internal architecture, I need to declare it on class level.

Comment: Why can't you just update `demo` the same way you update`demoName`?

Comment: @IshitaShah Whatever drives this requirement, please, do not call that *architecture*. What you are doing here is the exact opposite of a reasonable architecture.

Comment: Then: there is no need to put up screen shots here. Test code, and JUNit output, that is all text, and could be included as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to override class variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java)

Comment: @FrederikVantroys I have referred that solution, But its different scenario. Its override on class variable only, so static block is applicable. I have my local dynamic value by parameterized. I am getting dynamic value on method call.

Comment: Could this be an XY problem? You're looking for a "reference" variable, it seems. Could you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Arkadiy I am using things for Automation. I need to by pass one of the variable in to script query which is defined on class level. I do get variable value dynamic on method call. So as of now, I am assignning value of parameterized variable to global variable, which is part of script query. I want it to be override by local value, somehow if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Because `demoName` is `public`, you can reassign it from anywhere using `Demo.demoName = "abc";`, no need for a subClass at all.

**However**, using a public static variable and reassignating is awful. If you just want to override it at instance level in a subclass, you should use an accessor and override the **accessor** :

```
public static class Demo {
    public static String demoName = "xyz";

    public String getDemoName() {
        return demoName;
    }
}

public static class Demos extends Demo {

    private String demoNameOverride;

    @Override
    public String getDemoName() {
        return demoNameOverride;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> String is Immutable in java

***Note:*** when two String variables are referencing to the same object, if one variable changes its object  at any stage , it only changes that variable Object  not the other variable Objects.

```
 String demo = demoName;
```

at this line of code both variables are referencing to the same object `xyz`
which means demo and demoName have `xyz`. the reason why it is not changing its object after

```
@Test
    public void testtest() {
        test("abc");
    }
```

because **String is immutable in Java**. please refer [Why is String immutable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java/47121747)
https://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/

ex:

```
static String a="Helloworld";
static String b=a;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    a="World";
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);

}
```

output:

```
 Helloworld
 Helloworld
 World 
 Helloworld
```

this is how your programme logic flows now and b is referencing to its previous Object Only.after you change the String Value and again the reference has to be done.The below example will give you the idea.

```
public class Demo1 {

    public static String demoName = "xyz";
}

class Demo extends Demo1 {

    static String demo = demoName;

    public void test(String  variableName) {
        //initially i am calling both varaibles which you assign
        System.out.println(demoName);
        System.out.println(demo);
        // i am assigning the "abc" to demoName and calling both varaibales
        demoName = variableName;
        System.out.println(demoName);
        System.out.println(demo);
        // Now  i am assigning the "abc" to demo and calling both varaibales
        this.demo = variableName;
        System.out.println(demoName);
        System.out.println(demo);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo dem = new Demo();
        dem.test("abc");
    }

}
```

The Output is :

```
xyz
xyz
abc
xyz
abc
abc
```