# How do I delete the space character?

Tags: java, string, character, space

> Given a string, return a string made of the first two characters (if present), however include the first character only if it is 'o' and include the second only if it is 'z', so "ozymandias" yields "oz".

is the question I'm trying to solve. I can't change characters to be empty strings. I know the code is messy, but I'm trying to find out how to make the characters empty strings without using null character, Unicode, or min_value, etc. How do I do it?

```
public String startOz(String str) {
  char a = ' ';
  char b = ' ';
  String c = "";
  String d ="";
  if(str.length() <= 1){
    if(str.length() == 0){
      return "";
    }
    else
      if(str.charAt(0) == 'o'){
        return str;
      }
      else;
        return "";

  }
  else{

    if(str.charAt(0) == 'o'){
      a = 'o';
      c = Character.toString(a);
    }
    else;
      c = Character.toString(a);
      c = c.substring(1);
    if(str.charAt(1) == 'z'){
      b = 'z';
      d = Character.toString(b);
    }
    else;
      d = Character.toString(b);
      d = d.substring(1);

    c = Character.toString(a);
    d = Character.toString(b);
    return c + d;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to replace anything. Think of it as building a new string from scratch.

Comment: Also I recommend using better variable names, using `a` `b` `c` and `d` is a nightmare for anyone trying to figure out the code, including yourself.

Comment: You are setting your variables `String c` and `String d` redundantly many times. Setting a value only to immediately discard it and setting it to something else makes little sense. Having empty else blocks like `else;` also isn't really doing much except bloating your code. Removing some of the unnecessary code your code already becomes much more compact. And if you just get rid if the pointless char variables and instead directly work from building up an empty String you'll also get the result you want:  https://ideone.com/skH6BO

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the objective, but would it be met with `str = str.replaceAll("^oz.*", "oz");`? (Not that I'm saying you should do it like that)

Comment: @g00se no. `startOz("open")` should return `"o"` and `startOz("azimuth")` should return `"z"`. That is, if I understand OP correctly.

Comment: `return ((str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(0) == 'o') ? "o" : "") + ((str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(1) == 'z') ? "z" : "");`?

Comment: Related: [Why is String immutable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm trying to find out how to make the characters empty strings ..."*

You can't, you'll need to use a *String* value.

You are implying the following.  Which is a syntax error.

```java
char a = '';
```

It's because the *char* is a primitive data-type, thus it requires a value.

Whenever I run into this situation, I switch to a *String* value.

Answer (score -1):

To **achieve** the desired behavior without using empty strings, null characters, Unicode characters, or minimum values, you can **modify** your code as follows:

```
public String startOz(String str) {
  String result = "";

  if (str.length() >= 1 && str.charAt(0) == 'o') {
    result += str.charAt(0);
  }

  if (str.length() >= 2 && str.charAt(1) == 'z') {
    result += str.charAt(1);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This answer looks AI generated