# I can't create an unwanted side effect with a shallow copy

Tags: java

I just wanted to create a shallow and a deep copy of an object. I know that in the deep copy you create a new object with the values of the object you want to copy to prevent a side effect. The thing I noticed I can't get a side effect on my shallow copy, but I don't understand why.

```
public class Joo {
    public String name;
    
    public Joo(String a) {
        this.name = a; 
    }
    public Joo(Joo a) {
        this.name = a.name; 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Joo a = new Joo("Bernt");
        Joo b = new Joo(a);
        
        System.out.println("a :" +a.name); //a :Bernt
        System.out.println("b :" +b.name); //b :Bernt

        b.name = "Ernie";
        System.out.println("a :" +a.name); //a :Bernt 
        System.out.println("b :" +b.name); //b :Ernie
    }
}
```

I was expected that when I change b.name its also changes a.name because b.name is just the reference of the a.name object and not a real copy.

Comment: "because b.name is just the reference of the a.name object and not a real copy" Yeah, but by doing `b.name = "Ernie"`, you are making `b.name` refer to something else. It no longer is "just the reference of the a.name object".

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick answer :) . Okay than I got the sideeffect part wrong. How do I then force a sideeffect ?

Comment: Both are a deep copy... Your second constructor is identical to calling `this(a.name)`, that is, calling your first constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because `b.name` is just the reference of the `a.name` object and not a real copy"

Yeah, that is true, until you wrote `b.name = "Ernie"`. That makes `b.name` a reference to something else (namely, the string "Ernie"). That is what the `=` operator does. `b.name` no longer is "just the reference of the `a.name` object".

So you need to change `b.name` in some way, without making it a reference to something else.

However, there is no way to do this. [`String` is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22397861/5133585). After the `String` is created, there is no method you can call, or (public) fields you can set, that can change what string the `String` object represents. On the other hand, you can assign a new object to an existing `String`, like you are doing here.

Arguably, this is one of the reasons why `String` is immutable. Making a shallow copy of `String` will not cause any unwanted side effects, so you don't actually need to deep copy `String`s.

To see the side effects, use a mutable type, like `StringBuilder`:

```
public class Joo {
    public StringBuilder name;

    public Joo(String a) {
        this.name = new StringBuilder(a);
    }

    public Joo(Joo a) {
        this.name = a.name;
    }
}
```

Rather than assigning a new instance of `StringBuilder`, mutate the object by calling one of its methods:

```
b.name.append("Something");
```

Now it prints:

```
a :Bernt
b :Bernt
a :BerntSomething
b :BerntSomething
```

Comment: Wow thank sooo much , I got it now.
I never new that a String is immutable because all the examples for a shallow copy form my professor stated that the shallowCopy can now also change the original String. 
Now I am really confused why she said that.